# Chome - Deleting elements from height specified flexbox item display issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, overflow

I am having a chrome specific issue with removing elements from a flexbox item from a height specified flexbox container. This is causing strange display issues for another scrollable flexbox item within that container. It seems that the scrollable item is not properly refresh/repainting, while it is growing.

This is a fairly specific question that's easier to see in the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/gajv6snz/
Note: This is not specific to removing the elements using javascript. Manually deleting them in DevTools causes this also.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>

#container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Removing elements from #box1 causes display issues with box2 */
#box2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I expect that bottom scrollable flexbox item to take over the full container once the top flexbox item has been emptied. I want the container to remain the same size throughout.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 77 for me. Can you still reproduce it ?